# Remove Row Count from Pandas Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to ingest a csv file, pull only one column, and output it to a text file. My issue is that when it outputs, it adds a row with the row number. I need that row number to not exist.

So far I've tried the following code: (print will be replaced with file.write(df) when/if I get this working.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
file=open('BlockedIPs.txt', 'w')

df = pd.read_csv('IPOutput.csv', dtype='object')
df = df['IP Address (Impacted)'].astype('str')
#df = DataFrame(df) #I've commented these two lines out because they return "None"
#df = df.set_index('IP Address (Impacted)', inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Actual output is:

```
...        ...
44036      185.176.27.18
44037     51.143.106.177
44038     51.143.106.177
44039     51.143.106.177
44040    173.194.152.170
44041    173.194.152.170
44042    173.194.152.170
44043    173.194.152.123
44044    173.194.152.123
44045    173.194.152.123
```

Expected output is:

```
185.176.27.18
51.143.106.177
51.143.106.177
51.143.106.177
173.194.152.170
173.194.152.170
173.194.152.170
173.194.152.123
173.194.152.123
173.194.152.123
```

Answer (score 6):

The 'row number' you are referring is an index to the dataframe.  If you don't specify an index, Pandas creates one for you automatically.  An index, some row identifier, is required for Pandas so you can specify a column of your dataset to be that index, you can create a new one or you can let Pandas do it (default).

If you want to specify a column of your file to be the index, specify the value for the parameter `index_col` which can be a single column or a list of columns.

See the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv).

If you want to output the file without an index you can simply set the `index` parameter of the `to_csv` function to `False` (by default it is `True`)